# swift for loop not looping enough times

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I have a tableView in my app, and when i load the app I want the view to be populated with a list of dogs (retrieved from a server).

I have this working, but it will only load the first dog in the list from the server.

here's the code starting from where it serialises the JSON response from the server

```
do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! [AnyObject]
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            if let theDogs = json[0] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for dog in theDogs {
                    print("Dog")
                    if let ID = dog["ID"] as? String {
                        print(ID + " Safe")
                        let thisDog = Dog(name: (dog["Name"] as? String)!, surname: (dog["Surname"] as? String)!, id: (dog["ID"]  as? String)!, boarding: true)
                        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.dogs.count, inSection: 0)

                            // code here
                        self.dogs.append(thisDog)
                        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)


                    }
                }
            }
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            })
        } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
```

here's a copy of the logs (which includes a printed response from the server)

```
Optional([[{"ID":"47","Name":"Sparky","Surname":"McAllister"}],
[{"ID":"31","Name":"Maddie","Surname":"Crawford"}]])
Dog
47 Safe
```

as you can see from the log, there are 2 dogs on this list.
I would expect to see `Dog` printed twice in the log if the loop was working and `31 Safe` if it was getting to the part of the code that creates a new `Dog` object.

I can't work out what i've done wrong, can anyone see my problem?

thanks

Comment: The structure of your JSON is strange. It's an array of array of only one dictionary. Really strange. So `theDogs` should be [AnyObject], and you should loop there with `if let aDog = dog[0] as [String:AnyObject]` or something like that.

Comment: My PHP was self taught... I never worked out how to get rid of that first array  I probably should post a question about it lol....

Comment: Your JSON would have more sense like that: `[{"ID": "47","Name": "Sparky","Surname": "McAllister"}, {"ID": "31","Name": "Maddie","Surname": "Crawford"}]` Just an array of dogs, where a dog is a dictionary. Then you would have to keep your code, and change just this line: `if let theDogs = json[0] as? [[String: AnyObject]]` into `if let theDogs = json as? [[String: AnyObject]]`

Comment: yeh, I was never able to work out why it's like that... couldn't find the bit of code that was making the second array 

Answer (score 1):

Because the JSON is an Array of Arrays containing one dictionary each when you call `if let theDogs = json[0]` you get this part of the JSON:   `[{"ID":"47","Name":"Sparky","Surname":"McAllister"}]`
You would need to call `if let theDogs = json[1]` to get this part of the JSON:

```
[{"ID":"31","Name":"Maddie","Surname":"Crawford"}]
```

Comment: so what if i removed that line and just did `for dog in json`?

Comment: wait... i think i see it... i do as i just mentioned and then `let aDog = dog[0]` as was in the comments of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Travis' answer I was able to see where i'm going wrong. I just made a little tweak to his suggestion so i'm posting as an answer.

as Travis said, I need too access `json[1]` but i could have 7 different dogs on that list!

so i made the following changes:

```
 if let theDogs = json[0] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
```

is now:
     if let theDogs = json as? [[AnyObject]] {

which means in the for loop i'm accessing the root array.

I then changed the for loop from:

```
for dog in theDogs{
```

to:
    for aDog in theDogs{
    let dog = aDog[0]

which means for every array in theDogs, i'll get the only object in the array and call it dog.
problem solved, and future proofed.

thanks to everyone that helped!

Comment: A better solution might be to fix the JSON output by the server to a simpler structure (array of dictionaries) which would then lead to your code being cleaner but that assumes you have control of the server in order to change it.

Comment: The app is for my parents, they needed it urgently (for business)... I'm just going to make it work, and fix it all after they have started using it

Comment: Fair enough. The only issue with the solution above is that if the server did ever put more than one dog dictionary into the inner array for some reason, it would be missed because of the line "for aDog in theDogs{ let dog = aDog[0]". If you wanted to really future proof it then you would need to loop through any dictionaries in the inner array as well.

Comment: This is true, Hopefully by next week I'll be in a position to fix the server and begin fixing the various places that i use this code, when i do that, I'll be trying to make it one array of dictionaries instead of this mess i have just now haha